# To catch or not to catch

Tags: c++, linux, signals

Should application catch "bad" signals such as SIGSEV, SIGBUS?

Comment: I don't do C++ and do not know about SIGSEV/BUS but everything that interrupts a programs normal flow should be caught.

Comment: @abloodywar: No, it shouldn't.

Comment: @abloodywar: You should read up on how to program with exceptions, especially system exceptions that can be fatal.

Comment: @abloodywar: You must be assuming that if the exception is caught then the system can be returned somehow to a normal operating state.  This assumption is very incorrect.  Overzealous exception handling is the source of many nasty and near-impossible to fix bugs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those signals are produced in "should never happen" circumstances, when your program is in an undefined state. If you did catch them, continuing execution would be extremely problemeatic, as it would almost certainly cause more, possibly even more severe, errors. Also, if you don't catch them, the OS may be able to do things like produce useful diagnostics such as core dumps. So I would say "no", unless you don't want the core dump, and your error handling does something very simple such as write to a log and terminate.

Comment: Is there some way to catch, handle (e.g. save work) and then re-throw?

Comment: @Space_Cowboy If you do that, the program will be in a different state, so the core isn't so useful.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: Sure, you can catch the signal and raise() it again. But "save work" is difficult in a situation where e.g. your app's file descriptor pool could be overwritten with FFT calculations or a list of grandma's cookie recipe from the database.

Comment: I certainly understand the point of this. But I also hate programs that crash without at least trying to save my work. If there is a bug in the about box, or parsing someone entrying "x" instead of "2" for number of copies to print then that isn't likely to have corrupted anything and I would at least like it to try to save. You certainly DO need to be very careful though

Comment: @JB At the point an app receives  a SIGBUS, or whatever, it's to late to save your work. A well written app will have been journaling changes before this happens, which is how recovery mechanisms generally work.

Answer (score 4):

Only if you have something more meaningful to do than the default action.  You can't do very much more than aborting quite rapidly but sometimes trying to save the current work is adequate.  But pay attention at not overwriting existing files -- users don't like the replacement of good files even if outdated with garbage.

Comment: This is good. You might also want to try to write out some form of debugging information too to give the developer a better chance and working out what went wrong.

Comment: There are few cases where you need this. E.g. on Linux you can always get a core dump if desired.

Answer (score 1):

No you should not. I know it's tempting. But there are only very very few reasons why you would ever want to catch fatal signals such as SIGSEV and SIGBUS.

One of the few exceptions might be to have some extra signalling/postmortem code which tells that your program has failed. Even this should only be done in controlled environments, not in code that ships to hundreds of thousands of users.

You have to be prepared that your postmortem code itself will crash though because SIGSEV and SIGBUS are signs of defective code or data.

Answer (score 0):

There can be situation where you must catch signals like SIGSEGV and SIGBUS: one such example is: your pointer points to a mmaped region of memory and you are doing *ptr=x and for example this memory address belongs to a network file and your network is throwing some errors. at this point the only way to do error checking is catch the signal and retry or do something else.